# NSDate and different timezones?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, timezone, nsdate

Alright. Our application sends an `NSString` made out of the current user's username and todays date formatted in `yyyyMMddHH`. Our server, that is located in sweden, makes the exact same `String` and compares the two when it gets the call.

Now. We have realized, that if one of our users goes abroad, the timezone will change, resulting in complications.

if the iPhone user were to be in lets say, Seoul, South-korea. His `NSString` that is sent would be something like:

```
2011061718
```

Meanwhile, when our server gets the call, it will recreate its own datestring in this format because it's located in sweden.

```
2011061711
```

And therefore deny the user access to the functions on the server side.

To summarize:

How do i programmatically set a default static timezone in my application?

Atm we do this:

```
NSDate *aDate = [aDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

And somehow we need the timezone and compare the difference between the user's actual timezone and change it to a swedish-timezone.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Ok. This application is only meant to be released in sweden. And we are using a combination of the user's username and the current date in the format of yyyyMMddHH to make a secure key, the key is meant to update itself whenever a new hour starts. The server, which is located in sweden in the timezone of GMT+1 makes a verification that the user is on an actual device using the application and not someone who has made a client of his own making soap-calls to our service.

Therefore, if one of our users goes outside the timezone, it will reject the user since the strings wont match.

This is why we want to set the default timezone for that function GMT+1 at all times. And this is what we're really looking for.

Thanks. Again.

Comment: That last line - you get a string from a date and store it in a date?

Comment: Sweden is not in the time zone GMT+1. It uses GMT+1 in the winter and GMT+2 in the summer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to make the client format the date, this is how to do it:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Stockholm"]; // Sets the right time.
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]; // Forces the date formatter to accept any format string.
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setCalendar:gregorianCalendar];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHH"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];

NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];

NSLog(@"Date: %@", dateString);

[locale release];
[gregorianCalendar release];
[formatter release];
```

The date formatter will do all the work for you, you just need to configure it.

By setting the gregorian calendar, you're using the same calendar as in Sweden.

By setting the timezone, you'll get the time as it would be in Sweden.

By setting the locale to "en_US_POSIX" you make the formatter use the exact format you specify, and not append any AM/PM stuff.

Comment: @Da_smokes This will give you the correct time in Sweden from any location in the world.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mess about with that. Send complete date time as a string and let the server figure out the times.

```
NSString *dtString = [[NSDate date] description];
```

This will create a string with the format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM
```

Comment: There is no more context. This is a complete answer. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: This is a bad solution in my opinion. The format of the output of `NSDate`'s description method is not defined. Apple could change it in any future release.

Comment: The point is not the format - it's that the string contains the date, time *and* timezone. This can then be sent to the server, where it can be converted back into an NSDate and the server can compare it however it likes independently of the timezone where it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-[NSDateFormatter setTimeZone:]`. `NSDate` has nothing to do with it as it does not care about time zones.

Btw, your code will also fail if the user uses a different calendar.

Comment: As I said, use `-setTimeZone:`.

Answer (score 0):

Also a heads up, if you turn the AM/PM function on the dateformatter will pring out 'AM/PM' even if you dont place it in the format string.
To fix this also add an NSLocale to the DateFormatter.